# Little Endian addressing

Tags: assembly, architecture

In memory with address convention Little Endian next bytes of memory starting from 0x100120 have following data: `0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05`.

After loading 2 bytes from address 0x100121 into register A, what is the value of that register?

Comment: [What do you think](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?

Comment: So the value of register is "10" ?

Comment: No. 10 is completely wrong. Not just in terms of endian,  but also in terms of size and which data is copied. Some tipps: 1. How many bytes long is 0x01? 2.to what does an address point? To what does an address point when you increase the address by one? 3. what does endian affects exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**0x100120 have following date 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05.**

0x100120 has 0x01
0x100121 has 0x02 <-- first byte
0x100122 has 0x03 <-- second byte
0x100123 has 0x04
0x100124 has 0x05

When reading 2 bytes from an address the first byte goes to the low part of the A register and the second byte goes to the high part of the A register.
So AL=0x02 and AH=0x03
This gives AX=0x0302 (770 decimal)